# Reason for range for and decomposition not allowing constexpr

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17, constexpr, static-assert

I wanted to do a couple of sanity tests for a pair of convenience functions that split a 64-bit integer in two 32-bit integers, or do the reverse. The intent is that you don't do the bit shifts and logic ops all over again with the potential of a typo somewhere. The sanity tests were supposed to make 100% sure that the pair of functions, although pretty trivial, *indeed* works as intended.

Nothing fancy, really... so as the first thing I added this:

```
static constexpr auto joinsplit(uint64_t h) noexcept { auto [a,b] = split(h); return join(a,b); }
static_assert(joinsplit(0x1234) == 0x1234);
```

... which works perfectly well, but is less "exhaustive" than I'd like. Of course I can follow up with another 5 or 6 tests with different patterns, copy-paste to the rescue. But seriously... wouldn't it be nice to have the compiler check a dozen or so values, within a pretty little function? No copy-paste? Now that would be cool.

With a recursive variadic template, this can be done (and it's what I'm using in lack of something better), but it's in my opinion needlessly ugly.

Given the power of `constexpr` functions and range-based `for`, wouldn't it be cool to have something nice and readable like:

```
    constexpr bool test()
    {
        for(constexpr auto value : {1,2,3}) // other numbers of course
        {
            constexpr auto [a,b] = split(value);
            static_assert(value == join(a,b));
        }
        return true; // never used
    }
    static_assert(test()); // invoke test
```

A big plus of this solution would be that in addtion to being much more readable, it would be obvious from the failing `static_assert` not just that the test *failed in general*, but also the exact value for which it failed.

This, however, doesn't work for two reasons:

1. You cannot declare `value` as `constexpr` because, as stated by the compiler: *"The value of `__for_begin` is not usable in a constant expression"*. The reason for that is also explained by the compiler: *"note: `__for_begin` was not declared `constexpr`"*. Fair enough, *that is a reason*, silly as it may be.
2. Decomposition declaration cannot be declared `constexpr` (which is promptly followed by a non-constexpr condition for `static_assert` error).

In both cases, I wonder if there is truly a hindrance to allowing these being `constexpr`. I understand why it doesn't work (see above!), but the interesting question is *why is it like that?*

I acknowledge that declaring `value` as `constexpr` is a lie to begin with since its value obviously is not constant (it's different in each iteration). On the other hand, any value that it ever takes is from a compiletime constant set of values, yet without the `constexpr` keyword the compiler refuses to treat it as such, i.e. the result of `split` is non-`constexpr` and not usable with `static_assert` although it really is, by all means.
OK, well... I'm probably really asking too much if I want to declare something that has a changing value as constant. Even though from some point of view, if *it is* constant, in each iteration's scope. Somehow... is the language missing a concept here?

I acknowledge that range-based `for` is, like lambdas, really just a hack that mostly works, and mostly works invisibly, not a true language feature -- the mention of `__for_begin` is a dead giveaway on its implementation. I also acknowledge that it's generally tricky (forbidding) to allow the counter in a normal `for` loop being `constexpr`, not only because it's not constant, but because you can in principle have any kind of expressions in there, and it *truly* cannot be easily told in advance what values in general will be generated (not with reasonable effort during compiletime, anyway).
On the other hand, given an exact finite sequence of literals (which is as compiletime-constant as it can get), the compiler should be able to do a number of iterations, each iteration of the loop with a different, compiletime-constant value (unroll the loop if you will). Somehow, in a readable (non-recursive-template) manner, such thing should be possible?
Am I asking too much there?

I acknowledge that a decomposition declaration is not an altogether "trivial" thing. It might for example require calling `get` on a tuple, which is a class template (that could in principle be anything). But, whatever, `get` happens to be `constexpr` (so that's no excuse), and also in my concrete example, an anonymous temporary of an anonymous struct with two members is returned, so public direct member binding (to a `constexpr` `struct`) is used.
Ironically, the compiler even *does exactly the right thing* in the first example, too (and with recursive templates as well). So apparently, it's quite possible. Only just, for some reason, not in the second example.
Again, am I asking too much here?

The likely correct answer will be "The standard doesn't provide that".

Apart from that, are there any true, technical reasons why this cannot, could not, or *should not* work? Is that an oversight, an implementation deficiency, or intentionally forbidden?

Comment: Can you use a `constexpr` function with a regular `for` loop? Why does it have to be range-for?

Comment: @user2296177: That would probably (haven't tried) not work, again the counter would not be `constexpr`. But even if it worked, the immense advantage of using range-based for is that you can use arbitrary numbers in the list (not just 1,2,3 -- but e.g. 0x4957fea78d). With a simple loop, you would need an excessive number of iterations to sufficiently cover the range of inputs, both being a problem for compiletime-impact, and for running against a implementation limit. Range-based for lets you do that with a dozen values total, with reasonable safety.

Comment: @user2296177:  Worded differently, if you do some bit-trickery (like in my example), what you're defending against is first and foremost the wrong shift distance, and maybe endianness issues. Which means that if e.g. 0x01, 0xff, 0xff00 0xff0000, and 0xff00000000 all pass the test, then most probably _all_ possible numbers will pass. With a range-based for, you put those few constants, plus a few random ones all in one statement, which is nice and concise. With a regular for loop, that's not possible.

Comment: I meant something like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07a20c7d45d9ad75

Comment: It's hard to have a `constexpr` iterator since iterators themselves have state that must be modified (i.e. `++ptr` to advance). I believe I've seen some `constexpr` counters, but I've never used them; maybe you can implement something by looking into that.

Comment: @Damon: "*Somehow, in a readable (non-recursive-template) manner, such thing should be possible?*" Should it be possible? Sure. But *not* with that syntax. There have been plenty of `constexpr for` proposals or ideas which do what you ask. They haven't really moved forward since nobody behind them has been pushing them anywhere. They're often tied together with reflection/code generation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer you theoretical questions (" is the language missing a concept here?", " such thing should be possible? Am I asking too much there?", "there any true, technical reasons why this cannot, could not, or should not work? Is that an oversight, an implementation deficiency, or intentionally forbidden?") but, from the practical point of view...

> With a recursive variadic template, this can be done (and it's what I'm using in lack of something better), but it's in my opinion needlessly ugly.

I think that variadic templates is the right way and (you tagged C++17), using folding, there is no reason to recursivize it.

By example

```
template <uint64_t ... Is>
static constexpr void test () noexcept
 { static_assert( ((joinsplit(Is) == Is) && ...) ); }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstdint>

static constexpr std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t> split (uint64_t h) noexcept
 { return { h >> 32 , h }; }

static constexpr uint64_t join (uint32_t h1, uint32_t h2) noexcept
 { return (uint64_t{h1} << 32) | h2; }

static constexpr auto joinsplit (uint64_t h) noexcept
 { auto [a,b] = split(h); return join(a, b); }

template <uint64_t ... Is>
static constexpr void test () noexcept
 { static_assert( ((joinsplit(Is) == Is) && ...) ); }

int main()
 {
    test<1, 2, 3>();
 }
```

**-- EDIT --** Bonus answer

Folding (C++17) is great but never underestimate the power of comma operator.

You can obtain the same result (well... quite same) in C++14 with an helper function and the initialization of an unused array

```
template <uint64_t I>
static constexpr void test_helper () noexcept
 { static_assert( joinsplit(I) == I, "!" ); }

template <uint64_t ... Is>
static constexpr void test () noexcept
 {
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0, (test_helper<Is>(), 0)... };
 }
```

Obviously after a little change in `joinsplit()` to make it C++14 compliant

```
static constexpr auto joinsplit (uint64_t h) noexcept
 { auto p = split(h); return join(p.first, p.second); }
```

Comment: Folding! Folding!!! I didn't think of that, this is an ingenious idea. And there, I never understood what folding expressions were really good for. That's a great example.

Comment: @Damon - Thanks. You're so enthusiast that I've added a bonus C++14 example.

Comment: Using folding also seems to take only 1/3 the processing time compared to recursive templates, at least for my test case. While saving 2/3 on something that is a mere 30ms may seem like not a lot (in particular when you compare to link times), this is definitively something to keep in mind if you have considerably more iterations.